# stale element exception : click on report link in page then back button and so on

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

AS shown in the image : i want to click on each link one by one , on clicking :window does not gets change but it refresh.

clicking in the report link navigate to the next page, where clicking on back link it navigates back to the same page.

once it take back to the same page , locator no longer identify the next report link & throws stale element exception

[image: image 3]
 [image: image 2]

[image: Image 1]

```
public void getreports(String reportname) throws Exception
List<WebElement> li=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//tbody/tr/th/following::
tr/td//div/a"));

for(WebElement e: li)   {

if(reportname.equalsIgnoreCase(e.getText())) {
utilities.wait_control(e);
e.click();
break;
}
else if(reportname.equalsIgnoreCase("all"))
{

utilities.wait_control(e);
e.click();

NetReports ld = PageFactory.initElements(driver, NetReports .class);
ld.Netsubcategoryreport_backbutton.click();
Thread.sleep(2000); 
} }
```

Comment: There might be a frame change or child page is opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a small adjustment to your loop:

```
String selector = ".//tbody/tr/th/following::tr/td//div/a";
List<WebElement> li=driver.findElements(By.xpath(selector));
for (int i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    li=driver.findElements(By.xpath(selector));
    WebElement e = li.get(i);
    //Rest of your logic goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- StaleElementReferenceException -

  As the name suggests this exception occurs when the element stale, which means the element reference on which you are trying to take a action upon is no longer available on the page or has changed.

  To avoid this exception, try to find the element as and when you need to 
  take an action upon it rather than getting the element at some point of code 
  and then reusing it at different places.